# Web server slow on lan using URL, fast using local IP

Tags: networking, dns, apache-http-server, lan, html

I have a web (HTTP) server set up behind a router in my house. I have set it up to use DuckDNS with a subdomain name. For the purpose of this explanation I'll say that the subdomain is sub1.duckdns.org (that is not the actual domain) and I have forwarded port 80 to the server.

From outside my lan the server provides pages really fast and works great. I had a friend across town test it and he sees pages fine. I also tested on my smart phone. Also fine when typing in sub1.duckdns.org into any outside web browser.

The problem is when I try to access the server using that subdomain from inside my lan for testing. It's very very slow and most of the time the connection is reset before any usable output. If the page does load it is missing the css. However, if I type in the IP address of the machine (192.168.0.x) in my web browser it loads fast again.

Is there some setting in apache that will correct this problem or do I have to keep using the IP address when I am trying to view that computer from inside my lan?

Comment: Your modem/router probably doesn't do NAT loopback for your home Internet public IP. What happens is when you ask your computer (in your LAN) to get your sub1.duckdns.org URL the DuckDNS turns that into the IP address you've asked it to direct to (your home Internet IP so people can see your pages). Your modem/router receives that IP (crude) but it notices that it's its own IP and can't work out what to do with it because it's calling itself. The modem/router must be able to do NAT loopback do it can go "you've asked for something I already provide, let's forward the request to the LAN".

Comment: @Big Chris Ok, that makes sense. I assumed this was something with DNS or the server. Not an expert on NAT but your answer suffices. Unfortunately I looked around the router settings for some sort of NAT loopback option and there isn't one so it looks like I'm stuck working with the lan IP for testing and will have to hope the DNS is working for everyone else.

Comment: To fix this you have two options: 1) ask your ISP if they do and can provide a suitable modem/router that can do what you want (mainly businesses get these) - or you buy your own (but ask your ISP if they do NAT loopback). Or 2) you put an entry in your local computer hosts file to point your domain to your local IP - so your computer never contacts duckdns for the IP.

Comment: The hosts file is useful as you'll still be able to use the domain name in your browser...

Answer (score 0):

I have found this same problem on two different routers and a subnet over a WiFi relay.

The only fix I have found is to map your domains to the private IP address in the hosts file.

Comment: The only thing the three devices had in common was a remote access interface at port 80 that I deactivated.